# "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (<%%>)

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked a lot. but this is my specific problem.

i have this simple code:

```
<script>
    function ArrowClick(drp) {
        alert(drp);
    }
</script>


<div class="arrow" onclick="ArrowClick('<%= arrowValueLister.ClientID %>')"></div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="arrowValueLister" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
```

somehow this code works by alerting the client id of arrowValueLister. however as you might guess, the page displays the error stated above. the error was resolved when i tried "<%#" instead of "<%=", however it wont alert the client id.

i'd appreciate some advice on this. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing your piece of code to runat="server" placeholder

```
...    

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="phWrap">
  <div class="arrow" onclick="ArrowClick('<%= arrowValueLister.ClientID %>')"></div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>

...
```